# WKWebView - didFailProvisionalNavigation not called when a component fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I m trying to log an error when a page component loaded in a `WKWebView` fail, but `didFailProvisionalNavigation` is not called.

I removed a **css** file from my page to test with it, but no result.

When I load the page on Google Chrome I can find the missing file

[image]

The WKWebView is initialised as:

```
@interface MyWebView : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate>
@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *loginWebView;
@end
```

The .m file

```
@implementation MyWebView

- (void) initWebView {

    // Set and Load the WebView
    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}
```

Then I implemented the methods bellow:

```
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:
webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation:
webView:didFinishNavigation:
webView:didFailNavigation:withError:
webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:
```

The first three methods get called, but neither `didFailNavigation` nor `didFailProvisionalNavigation` are called

By looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455637-webview?language=objc) for `didFailProvisionalNavigation` we have

> Called when an error occurs while the web view is loading content.

Well, a content has failed (css file) and the method is not called, how can I do this?

PS : I also tried using `UIWebView`!

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Any solution found yet ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: Oh :-( That's not cool ! I will post here if Im able to find any solution.

Comment: That would be cool, thanks in advance mate

Comment: Any updates 2 years on? ;)

Comment: Nothing yet! I just gave up on this :'(

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler{
    NSInteger statusCode = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response).statusCode;
    NSLog(@"statusCode:%ld", statusCode);
    if (statusCode/100 == 4 || statusCode/100 == 5) {
        NSLog(@"webview error:%@", navigationResponse.response);
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
}
```

this works!